# Will `account` modules get checked if `auth` succeeded or failed?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

In the following PAM configuration for the file `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

If the first section (`auth`) succeeded, will the second section (`account`) get called and checked? And oppositely, if `auth` section failed, will `account` get called?

In another scenario, to emphasize **my main difficulty, if we mixed `auth` and `account`**, let us take the following example:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
account     required      pam_unix.so

auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
```

How will PAM behave exactly? I am confused about that, and it is going to be very helpful to me if some body can explain that for me.

Answer (score 2):

PAM does not mix auth and account type, but rather [stacks them independently](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam) according to the management type. The return value of a stack depends on the order of the options and the control flags, cf. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/pam-15/index.html

What is done with the result, depends a bit on the application. Typically a program like login or su validates an account only after a successful authentication.